# Vuetify autocomplete - set an initial search value?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, autocomplete, vuetify.js

I am pretty much at beginner level with vuetify and I would like to set the search value on a `<v-autocomplete>` in a `<v-dialog>`.

I expect a result <strike>like so</strike>: (edited)

[image: Not so]

More like that (edited: added image)

[image: More like that]

but the input field is empty.

I took the example code from:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/#nested-dialogs
and modified it a little bit like:

```
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog2" max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          Dialog 2
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-autocomplete 
                          :items="select" 
                          :search-input.sync="search" 
                          label="A Select List" 
                          item-value="text" 
                          return-object
                          autofocus
                          ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog2 = false">
            Close
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      dialog2: false,
      search: "1",
      select: [{ text: "State 1" }, { text: "State 2" }, { text: "Another 2" }, { text: "State 3" }]
    };
  },
  watch: {
    search(n, o) {
      console.log("watch search", n, o);
      // at some point search is set to null
      // reset it to the old value
      if (n === null) this.search = o;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.search = "2";
  }
});
```

I also made and updated (edited) a codepen:
https://codepen.io/joergwork/pen/xxVRwyE

Some ideas on that?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Yeah, I have to be more precise - I've edited the question above. I explicitly want to set the search expression. In reality  I do not know the items which I can select from - they should be loaded from a server after the search expression was entered. Therefore I can not set the `value`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a computed value:

**template**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-btn color="primary" class="ma-2" dark @click="dialog2 = true">
          Open Dialog 2
        </v-btn>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog2" max-width="500px">
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              Dialog 2
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-autocomplete :value="searchText" :items="select" :search-input.sync="search" label="A Select List" item-value="text" return-object autofocus></v-autocomplete>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog2 = false">
                Close
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed: {
    searchText() {
      return this.select[0] || ''
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dialog2: false,
      search: "1",
      select: [{ text: "State 1" }, { text: "State 2" }, { text: "Another 2" }, { text: "State 3" }]
    };
  },
  watch: {
    search(n, o) {
      console.log("watch search", n, o);
      // at some point search is set to null
      // reset it to the old value
      if (n === null) this.search = o;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.search = "2";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that does not solve my problem. I don't want to select an item, I just want to set the `search-item` text and additionally I'd like the "selection list" to be visible (like in the 2nd image).